# Troubles with Swift 2 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to work with Swift 2, but i have troubles with variables.
When I declare a var, Xcode shows this
[image]

I try with another code like

`if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        // ...
    }`

But is the same problem.

UITouch is not the only one with the problem, other variables too.

What i can do for fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _?

Comment: Is the suggestion, the original code is `let touch = touches.first as UITouch`

Comment: Yes, try it. It's warning not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have never used `touch` again in you code. It's an unused variable. Either consider removing it or you can fix it using the above fix.

This warning will go away once you use the touch variable.

e.g.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    print("\(touch)")
}
```

In above case `touch` is used in `print` method and hence there won't come any warning.

Comment: Good programer always keep `ZERO` warnings. Welcome to the elite group :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it. I try to do my best